# What are the possible reasons for the browser not to display an image completely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Does anyone know the possible reasons for the browser not displaying an image completely? It is as if the download or the rendering of the image was interrupted, preventing the image from loading completely, showing only part of it.

My application uses node and socket.io. Parts of the backend and frontend code are below.

**server.js**:

```
app.get('/imagem_do_servidor', function(req, res){  
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/static/uploads/default/' + email_user + '.jpg');   
});
```

**home.html**:

```
<script>
    socket.on('mensage', function(data){
        $("img#imagem_server").attr("src", "/static/imagens/load.gif");
        
        $("img#imagem_server").attr("src", data.url);   
             
        
        console.log('I heard a message ');                  
    });     

</script>
```

Comment: Please post your question in English only. If you want to use Portuguese, try on [pt.so]

Comment: That's not how you send a file with Express. You are supposed to place your static files in an `asset` folder and then `app.use( express.static('path/to/assets"))`. See [serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jeremy Thille. It worked perfectly for me.
as you said, just adding app.use (express.static ('public')) to my assets directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to place your static files in an asset folder and then `app.use( express.static('path/to/assets"))`. See [serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).